# How To install AWS SDK for PHP in wordpress?

Tags: uploads, media, amazon

I am going to install and use AWS SDK for PHP to facilitate uploads/list objects directly from the front-end of my WordPress instance to S3. What is the best practice to do that ?

P.S: I don't want to use plugins

Comment: When you say that you don't want to use plugins, do you mean you don't want to use existing plugins or that you don't want to make your own?

Comment: @getWeberForStackExchange i mean i don't want to write my own plugin

Comment: that almost certainly eliminates all the answers you could get, the easiest way is to create a plugin that has a single file that loads the SDK from a subfolder with `<?php /** plugin name: AWS SDK */ require_once( 'aws_sdk/....`, where `aws_sdk` is the folder where you put the SDK after downloading it. You're still going to have to write code to use that SDK to do stuff on the frontend though

Answer (score 0):

- Install Amazon Web Services Plugin. (https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-web-services/)
- Add all the required keys, at the AWS menu that now should be available in your WP dashboard.
- Include the library in your code, in my case was:

  require '/path/to/plugins/amazon-web-services/vendor/aws/aws-autoloader.php';
- Enjoy!

Comment: so he still needs to write a plugin.....

Comment: If all he wants is the SDK, no he doesn't

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a plugin you may want to read this post:

[How can I install AWS SDK for PHP in Wordpress without installing a Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42038363/3804360)